# Parameter adjustments for input data in shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make some adjustments to the code below. Notice that when you run the APP I have `radioButtons` with two options, Excel and Database. My idea is that if the person presses Excel then the `fileInput` will appear for the person to choose the excel file, if the person chooses the Database option, will have a connection to a database, therefore, in this second case, `fileInput` will not appear, it will only have a connection to the database. and the following will happen:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "[your driver's name]",
                      Server   = "[your server's path]",
                      Database = "[your database's name]",
                      UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                      Port     = 1433)

data <-tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date1")) %>%
       collect()
  
data2 <- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date2")) %>% 
          collect()
```

So I would like to make these adjustments to the code below.

**Executable code below:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("PAGE1",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 radioButtons("button", 
                                              label = h3("Data source"),
                                              choices = list("Excel" = "Excel", "Database" = "database"), 
                                              selected = "File"),
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),

                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                             
                            )))))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    else {
      df3 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath,sheetnames()[1])
      validate(need(all(c('date1', 'date2') %in% colnames(df3)), "Incorrect file"))  
      df4 <- df3 %>% mutate_if(~inherits(., what = "POSIXct"), as.Date) 
      return(df4)
    }
  })
  
  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    df1 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath,sheetnames()[2])
    df1
  })
  
  output$fileInput <- renderUI({
    fileInput("file",h4("Import file"), multiple = T, accept = ".xlsx")
  })
  
  sheetnames <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    available_sheets = openxlsx::getSheetNames(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `observe` to check the input from the `radiobutton`, if it is NULL, then don't render the fileInput, if it Excel chosen then render the excel input, if it database, then set the fileinput to NULL to remove the fileinput then do the database stuff.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinythemes)
library(readxl)




ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("PAGE1",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 radioButtons("button", 
                                              label = h3("Data source"),
                                              choices = list("Excel" = "Excel",
                                                             "Database" = "database"), 
                                              selected = "File"),
                                 uiOutput('fileInput'),
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 
                               )))))



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #hide("fileInput")
  
  observe({
    if(is.null(input$button)) {
      
    }else if (input$button =="Excel"){
      
      output$fileInput <- renderUI({
        fileInput("file",h4("Import file"), multiple = T, accept = ".xlsx")
      })
      
      data2 <- reactive({
        req(input$file)
        df1 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath,sheetnames()[2])
        df1
      })
      
      sheetnames <- eventReactive(input$file, {
        available_sheets = openxlsx::getSheetNames(input$file$datapath)
      })
      
      
    } else if(input$button=="database"){
      
      output$fileInput <- NULL
      
      con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                            Driver   = "[your driver's name]",
                            Server   = "[your server's path]",
                            Database = "[your database's name]",
                            UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                            PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                            Port     = 1433)
      
      data <-tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date1")) %>%
        collect()
      
      data2 <- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date2")) %>% 
        collect()
      
      
    } else {
      output$fileInput <- NULL
    }
    
    
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    else {
      df3 <- read_excel(input$file$datapath,sheetnames()[1])
      validate(need(all(c('date1', 'date2') %in% colnames(df3)), "Incorrect file"))
      df4 <- df3 %>% mutate_if(~inherits(., what = "POSIXct"), as.Date)
      return(df4)
    }
  })
  

  
  
  

  
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Sample:

[image]

Note, for the sample, I disabled the database stuff to demonstrate the removal of the fileinput

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay, from what I noticed you are missing to insert `data <-tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date1")) %>% collect()` and also `data2 <- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "date2")) %>% collect() ` in the server. Remembering `data` and `data2` are different when using database and when using `fileInput`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that. Does this now answer your question or is it still lacking?

Comment: Just one question: `data` and `data2` when using `fileInput`, don't need to be in `else if (input$button ="Excel")` or is there no need??

Comment: Oh yes they do, sorry about that